# .xprofile isn't enough

Tags: login, resolution, lightdm, default

I've been trying to find a solution on how to change the screen resolution on the login screen and other users. .xprofile will only affect my account. I've been searching for a few months but I got nothing. Please help. It would be easier if the "Default Resolution" was still there in the monitors settings. Plus, I'm afraid of editing the xorg.conf. Last time was ugly...

My specs:
HP dc5000 Small Form Factor
Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot i386
Intel Pentium 4 2.40 GHz
Intel 82865g x86/MMX/SSE2 Integrated Graphics (Standard Experience, OpenGL 1.3 and Runs Unity 3D :P)
SoundMax Integrated Audio Card
Broadcomm Integrated Ethernet
994.1 MiB RAM
38.3 GB HDD
Acer X203H (Maximum Resolution 1600x900)

Comment: Hi again. Looks like you'll have to learn to edit xorg.conf. Lots of guides out there to assist you. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#statically_setup_in_xorg.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Taken from comments:`]

> Looks like you'll have to learn to edit xorg.conf. Lots of guides out there to assist you. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#statically_setup_in_xorg.conf